# About using low-level functions

Tags: c, linux

I accommodated the comment and rewritten the code. But it still doesn't work.
I open a text file containing several sentences, change lowercase letters to uppercase letters and then try to enter them in another file.
I don't know well what to use for the third argument of read().
How can I correct the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fp,ftp,i,nread;
    char str[300];


    if(fp=open("text_in",O_RDONLY) < 0)
    {
            perror("open: ");
            exit(1);
    }

    if(ftp=open("text_w", O_WRONLY |O_CREAT , 0644) < 0)
    {
            perror("open: ");
            exit(1);
    }


    nread=read(fp,str,300);

    for(i=0; i<=nread; i++)
    {
            if((str[i] >= 'a') && (str[i] <= 'z'))
            {
                    str[i] -= ('a'-'A');
            }
    }

    write(ftp,str,nread);


    close(fp);
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing `sizeof(txt)`, knowing that you might have `read()` less?

Comment: Read the manuals. `open` fails with negative values. `0` is a valid filedescriptor. `read` may successfully return with less than `sizeof(txt)` and it definitely won't put a `'\0` after the read string -- use the returned number (if it's positive) as the length of the read string.

Comment: What @EOF says, plus 'strlen(txt)' Why?  read() returns a value - you should use it.  All that sizeof, strlen and the like is just wrong; unnecessary, unsafe, unwanted.

Comment: Your belief that you can simultaneously read and write the same file shows more ingenuity than most.

Comment: regarding: `int fp;`   the returned value from a call to `open()` is a file descriptor index, not a file pointer, suggest: `fd_in`  Similar considerations exist for `int ftp;`  Variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both), the variable names used in the posted code are misleading

Comment: before calling `exit()` should cleanup.  I.E. close open files, etc

Comment: Note: the posted code does NOT try to update the original file, but rather outputs to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

The following proposed code:

1. incorporates the comments to the question
2. documents why each header file is included
3. clarifies the code a bit via use of `toupper()`
4. properly checks for errors
5. cleans up after it self
6. uses meaningful variable names
7. eliminates the 'magic' numbers by giving them meaningful names
8. follows the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*
9. cleanly compiles
10. performs the desired function of reading a block (up to 300 characters in length) from the input file, converting all lower case characters to upper case, outputting that updated line to a new file.

And now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>    // perror()
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit()
#include <fcntl.h>    // open(), O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, O_CREAT
#include <unistd.h>   // read(), write(), close()
#include <ctype.h>    // toupper()

#define BUF_LENGTH 300

int main( void )
{
    int fdi;
    int fdo;
    char buffer[ BUF_LENGTH ];


    if( (fdi=open("text_in",O_RDONLY)) < 0)
    {
            perror("open: ");
            exit(1);
    }

    if( (fdo=open("text_w", O_WRONLY |O_CREAT , 0644)) < 0)
    {
            perror("open: ");
            close( fdi );  // cleanup
            exit(1);
    }


    ssize_t nread = read( fdi, buffer, BUF_LENGTH );
    if( nread <= 0 )
    { // then EOF or read error
        perror( "read failed" );
        close( fdi );
        close( fdo );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    for( ssize_t i=0; i<=nread; i++ )
    {
            buffer[i] = (char)toupper( buffer[i] );
    }

    ssize_t nwritten = write( fdo, buffer, (size_t)nread );
    if( nwritten != nread )
    {
        perror( "write all, bytes failed" );
    }

    close(fdi);
    close(fdo);
}
```